# How to make modal form un-minimize after a Show Desktop (or windows + D)

Tags: c++builder-xe5

When I start my application, the first and only form that shows is a login form in modal:

```
frmLogin = new TfrmLogin(Application);
frmLogin->Init();
if(frmLogin->ShowModal() == mrCancel)
{
  //this will exit the application because user cancel the login
  return -1;
}
```

There is code happening after the ShowModal which open the main form (not in modal) of the application.

When I press **Show Desktop** or do **windows + D** and I'm still on the modal form for the login, I can't get the login back when clicking on the taskbar.

**1.** Is there a way to un-minimize the modal login after a 'Show Desktop'?

**2.** Also, if I open my application and the login appears, I can't seem to be able to close it when right-clicking on it in the taskbar > 'Close windows'. Is there a way to close it by the taskbar? (It close perfectly when using the red 'x' in the corner of the login form though)

I'm using c++ Builder 10.1 Berlin

Comment: The issues are related to the fact that the Login Form does not have its own Taskbar button by default.  Only the `TApplication` or `Application.MainForm` window has a Taskbar button, depending on the `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` property. You can override the Login Form's `CreateParams()` method to force it to get its own Taskbar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Remy Lebeau suggested, I came to the solution by overriding the CreateParams() function.

In my Login.h

```
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params);
```

In my Login.cpp

```
void __fastcall TfrmLogin::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    TForm::CreateParams(Params);
    Params.ExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    Params.WndParent = GetDesktopWindow();
}
```

My code is based on the Delphi example found here:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244599

Now, my Login form is able to be un-minimized after a ctrl + D! 
Hopes this helps other c++ builder programmers out there.